# How to pause all CUDA threads until thread 0 finished some code?

Tags: cuda

I have a simple CUDA code below. My question is that how to make All thread pauses while thread 0 is initializing array data. So after that, all thread can access elements in data.

```
__device__ int *data;

__global__ void test() {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (idx == 0) {
        data = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof (int));
    }

    data[idx] = idx;
    printf("%d", data[idx]);
}

int main() {
    test << <1, 10 >> >();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only  CUDA provided way to do this (in the general case, where the kernel launch has more than 1 block) is via [cooperative groups grid synchronization](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization-cg).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929929/processing-shared-work-queue-using-cuda-atomic-operations-and-grid-synchronizati/63930239#63930239) provides an example of usage of cooperative groups grid-wide synchronization.

Since there is significant complexity to using cooperative groups, you might want to alternately consider just initializing this pointer in host code, before launching your kernel.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878410/cuda-object-copy/49879609#49879609) shows how that could be done.

In your particular case, where you are only launching one block, you can just use `__syncthreads()`:

```
if (idx == 0) {
    data = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof (int));
}
__syncthreads();
data[idx] = idx;
printf("%d", data[idx]);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much @Robert Crovella.